# LibreOffice page preview problem

Tags: libreoffice, appmenu

When the menu bar is enabled for LibreOffice, every time I click on the page preview, the program crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known bug. 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/754562 -- link to bug on launchpad
https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=natty -- ppa width fixed version.